# Read from AWS Secret Manager during .net core Startup

Tags: .net-core, startup, aws-secrets-manager

I have a .net core 3.1 web application that reads a variable from the AWS secret manager. I successfully make the call to the secret manager from within one of the controllers. But I'd instead like to make this call once during startup, and have this value available within my application to consume (rather than making the AWS secret manager call every time the controller is hit).

What is the best approach to use here? Should I use caching?

Comment: Is distributed your system?

Comment: distributed? It's a web application that exposes HttpGet and HttpPut endpoints.It's running in a docker container.

Comment: Then use this library https://github.com/aws/aws-secretsmanager-caching-net, get the secrets in startup

Comment: Thanks. Although I don't need the cache functionality. Anyway I can just read it once and have it available post startup running for as long as the application is running